# Checkbox not unchecked when list rerender

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have array of objects, objects have few property with "checked" property, and when i clicked on checkbox is checked, but when i switch for another list this check is stays checked , example:  [click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/URZWP.png) maybe you know a universal way to use checkbox?

I try use Checkbox from MUI, with attribute OnChange, example:

`<Checkbox className={classes.check} onChange={() => item.checked = !item.checked} size="small" color="primary"/>`

I'm going through an array of objects and the `item` is an object that has the checked property

Comment: You don't appear to be setting the state anywhere, if `item` is in the state, then the `item.checked = !item.checked` will be lost on re-render. You need to set state with the method provided. (Without a complete example, that's about as detailed as I can get)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this(take as an example), it might work:

Your list:

```
const list = [
 {
  id: 1,
  ...rest data
 },
 {
  id: 2,
  ...rest data
 },
{
  id: 3,
  ...rest data
}
];
```

Your **onChange** Function and take a one array state and store every **checked** id in that state and use it for showing checkbox:

```
 const [selectedEntryIds, setSelectedEntryIds] = useState([]);

 const onSelect = (id) => {
 if (!selectedEntryIds.includes(id)) {
  setSelectedEntryIds([...selectedEntryIds, id]);
 } else {
  setSelectedEntryIds([...selectedEntryIds.filter(item => item !== id)]);
}
};
```

Your checkbox code (Assume your mapping with list and sending id):

```
        <Checkbox
          showCheckIcon
          name={`checkbox-${item.id}`}
          onChange={() => onSelect(item.id)}
          checked={selectedEntryIds?.includes(item.id)}
        />
```